# htaccess rewrite and facebook like urls

Tags: facebook, .htaccess, facebook-like, url-rewriting

I have a path like:

```
http://mysite.com/detailpages/article/title
```

And I'd like to rewrite it to hide the detailpages folder like this

```
http://mysite.com/article/title
```

Now I understand this is doable with something like htaccess rewrite, but how does a service like the facebook like iframe handle this?

Would facebook use the whole url or the rewritten one?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would facebook use the whole url or the rewritten one?

It will use the one you tell it.

You have to be aware that rewriting like this is a server-internal thing – the outside world does not even have to know that you *internally* map something to something else.